# How to calculate R-squared after using bagging function to develop CART decision trees?

Tags: r, function, statistics, cart, decision-tree

I am using the following bagging function with ipred to bootstrap the sample 500 times in R in order to develop decision trees:

```
baggedsample <- bagging(p ~., data, nbagg=500, coob=TRUE, control = list 
(minbucket=5))
```

After this, I would like to know the R-squared.

I notice that if I do the bagging with caret function, R-squared would be automatically calculated as follows:

```
# Specify 10-fold cross validation
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",  number = 10) 

# CV bagged model
baggedsample <- train(
  p ~ .,
  data,
  method = "treebag",
  trControl = ctrl,
  importance = TRUE
  )

# assess results
baggedsample

RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
##   36477.25  0.7001783  24059.85
```

---

Appreciate any guidance on this issue, thanks.

Comment: `rsquared` should be calculated using `(1 - mse)/var(response)`. So you just need to evaluate the `mse` (mean squared error) and the variance of your `y`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not provide any data, I will illustrate using the built-in iris data.

You can simply compute R-squared from the formula.

```
attach(iris) 
BAG = bagging(Sepal.Length ~ ., data=iris)
R2 = 1 - sum((Sepal.Length - predict(BAG))^2) /
    sum((Sepal.Length - mean(Sepal.Length))^2)
R2
[1] 0.824782
```

Comment: Thank you for both of your help@RLaye @G5W, I tried both methods in my dataset, but the R2 are slightly different (within 2% ). I also tried the following codes which generate another slightly different R2, Why is that?                                   
>predict_bagged_m14 <- predict(bagged_m14, bagged.m14)

>bagged.m14$Prediction <- predict_bagged_m14

>head(bagged.m14)

>bagged.m14$rss <- (bagged.m14[,19]-bagged.m14[,18])^2

>bagged.m14$tss <- (bagged.m14[,18]-13.968)^2

# calcuate r squared
>1 - (sum(bagged.m14[,20])/sum(bagged.m14[,21]))